# QGIS: prefixPath() gives NULL in PyCharm

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, pycharm

I have installed QGIS 2.18, QGIS 3.8 and OSGeo on a Windows machine.

I tried to set up a PyCharm environment for PyQGIS coding, but I can't initialize the OGR provider to import shapefiles.

Here's the code:

```py
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.setPrefixPath(r'C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis', True)
qgs.initQgis()
```

When I try to run

```py
qgs = QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(r'C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis', True)
print(qgs)
```

It returns `None`. If I have installed three versions of QGIS in Windows there are some problems with `prefixPath()`?

Comment: Try defining the full path instead of the shorthand.

Comment: I've used the full path, is there another way to load the providers? In linux i use '/usr' as prefix path and it is right.

Comment: Now i have uninstalled all QGIS version and installed only QGIS3.8, but the problem is not solved. Did you mean using os.path.abspath(..)?

Comment: I'll try tomorrow on windows, thank you.

Comment: I have solved all the settings problems, thank you

Comment: Glad you got it working! You should post your solution as an **answer** below which could help others with similar problems :)

Comment: Yes, of course, wait a moment

Comment: I have the right batch file in the office

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the right batch file. It works for me, i use windows10, PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2.2 and OSGEO-QGIS3.8.

```
SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W64
SET QGISNAME=qgis
SET QGIS=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\%QGISNAME%
SET QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%QGIS%
SET PYCHARM="C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2.2\bin\pycharm64.exe"




set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python
set PYTHONHOME=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python37
set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages;%PYTHONPATH%

set QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Qt5\plugins\platforms
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis

set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis

call %OSGEO4w_ROOT%\bin\o4w_env.bat
call %OSGEO4w_ROOT%\bin\py3_env.bat
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\qt5_env.bat"

SET PATH=%PATH%;%QGIS%\bin
SET PYTHONPATH=%QGIS%\python;%PYTHONPATH%


@echo off
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass76\lib
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Qt5\bin
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Qt5\plugins
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Qt5\plugins
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Qt5\plugins\platforms
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin

start "PyCharm aware of QGIS" /B %PYCHARM% %*
```

Comment: Ok, thank you i am a novice in the blog